# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Procedures with Date as a Parameter causing exception

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE     PROCEDURE_ONE(
 T1_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
 Date_Start_P in Date Default sysdate
)
as
begin
OPEN T1_CURSOR FOR ...
```

This works when testing with Oracle SQL Developer

My VB.Net code doesn't like the parameter

```vb
Private Function Load_Aging_Stock() As DataTable
    Try
        Dim dba As New Data_Access_Class
        Dim strSQL As String = "JOHN.PROCEDURE_ONE"
        Dim dt As DataTable

        Dim cmd As OracleCommand = dba.CreateStoredProcCommand(strSQL)
        Dim oracleParameter(1) As OracleParameter
        oracleParameter(0) = New OracleParameter()
        oracleParameter(1) = New OracleParameter()

        cmd.BindByName = True
        With cmd
            oracleParameter(0) = cmd.Parameters.Add("T1_Cursor", dbType:=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output)
            '.Parameters.Add("T1_CURSOR", OracleClient.OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

            If Me.chk_No_Date_Start.Checked = False Then
                Dim tmpDate As String = CDate(Me.dt_Start_Date.Text.Trim).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                oracleParameter(1) = cmd.Parameters.Add("Date_Start_P", dbType:=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, val:=tmpDate, ParameterDirection.Input)
                '.Parameters.Add("Date_Start_P", OracleClient.OracleType.DateTime).Value = Me.dt_Start_Date.Text
            End If
        End With

        dt = dba.ExecuteSelectCmdDataTbl(cmd)

        Return dt

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim Err As New SS_Errors("frm__Report", "Load_Report", ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

I've also tried the same code but replaced Varchar2 with Date and both times, I get the same exception

> One of the identified items was in an invalid format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass the **string** as parameter value, just use the **Date** value, i.e.

```
oracleParameter(1) = cmd.Parameters.Add("Date_Start_P", dbType:=OracleDbType.Date, val:=CDate(Me.dt_Start_Date.Text.Trim), ParameterDirection.Input)
```